# Get password prompt in the terminal/shell

Tags: security, ui

When I am connecting a Mac through ssh, I don't have any GUI.

However, for some of the commands like `security find-internet-password`, there will be a GUI prompt for the admin's password. How can I have the prompt in the shell instead of GUI?

Comment: is security the only command you have issues with?

Comment: @Mark no, also for some node application. if you start an application from shell which listens to 0.0.0.0:port, there will be a prompt ask you do you want this application assess internet..

Answer (score 3):

I use this in Terminal

```
sudo security find-internet-password -gs www.facebook.com
```

that asks me to confirm with my Admin Password

then it delivers.

Answer (score -1):

This is by design, the security interface requires human interaction (well, GUI interaction). Normal keychain usage is done using an API which allows the user to grant the requesting application permanent access to the stored data for that request.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain why this is not a correct answer? If you simply don’t like the way Apple designed it, that’s fine, but that is not what votes are for.